# How to block Chrome from auto-filling text boxes?

Tags: php, javascript, css

I'm testing my website on Google Chrome and saw that this browser always auto-fills my username and password text boxes, even if I never said to do that. I don't want this behavior. Is there any way to stop this using PHP, CSS or JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `autocomplete="off"` on the fields you don't want auto-filled, but honoring that is up to the browser and isn't supported everywhere:

```
<input type="text" name="something" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Fyi, this is a non-standard attribute. It works, but non-standard...not that it really matters.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is a browser feature and you should be able to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
<form name="form1" autocomplete="off" action=""></form>
```

This applies for all form elements